# Convert a file to base64 using FileReader and Promises

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function to use promises to convert an uploaded file to base64 and trying to return the base64 string. Getting an HTTP Error 200 and I'm not sure if it's returning the right string.

```
function getBase64(file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        let base64String = reader.result.split(',').pop();
        deferred.resolve(base64String);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't use jQuery as your promise library. Now that Promises are standard in JS (even if not in the version you are targeting), you might as well use something standard-compliant, like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).  Also I am not sure what an "HTTP Error 200" is. 200 is the status code for a successful http request and I don't see any HTTP request being made above.

Comment: @barry-johnson I call the getBase64 function into a var img that'll get tweeted (using Codebird). When I post the tweet, I get the HTTP Error 200... How do I use Bluebird in this instance?

Comment: One more time: 200 is NOT an error. 200 is the HTTP success/OK status code.

Comment: @barry-johnson Oh sorry... I'm using Codebird to post to Twitter and I get this error with the HTTP 200: "Could not authenticate you." This only happened when I started using the promise...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with your Codebird/PHP issue. You should consider reformulating your question. If you have simply naively changed your `getBase64` function to return a promise when it used to return an actual base64 string and have not changed how it is called or the result manipulated, then a) you likely are trying to send a promise object when you want to send a string, and b) you may/will likely be executing that code before the onload function is triggered and the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `promise-file-reader`:

https://github.com/jahredhope/promise-file-reader